# bind a list of items into radautocomplexbox by code

Tags: c#, telerik

I want to use a radAutocompletebox in my application. The `ItemSource` is taken dynamically from my database. I have code like this:

```
 var list = extrainfo.database.UserPrivateInfoes;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            obs.Add( new RadAutoCompleteBoxItem{Content= item.UName} );
        }
       TX_Receiver.ItemsSource = obs;
```

which the obs is observablecollection .

the problem is when the items are shown in dropdown, I have an item with TWO CROSS BUTTON for remove. Actually it is not nice enough!! But when I add a list of `String` to `ItemSource` the problem is resolved. I need to have an item not just with a string for its name, I need more info (like UID) for every item.
Is there any solution??

here is my new code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomDropDownItemTemplate">
                <TextBlock 
                            Text="{Binding Content}" />
            </DataTemplate>

ItemsSource="{Binding obs}" DropDownItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomDropDownItemTemplate}" />

 public class Country
    {
        public string Content;
    }


obs.Add( new Country {Content= item.UName} );
```

when i DEBUG my code it add all data to itemsource correctly , but when i SELECT an item in Autocompletebox it shows nothing in the box. an EMPTY item with a cross button. i want to show the content!!!!

after exactly 24 hours!! i finally found my answer, DisplayMemberPath. yeah!1
 and this is my Code:

```
 var list = from item in extrainfo.database.UserPrivateInfoes
                       join gp in extrainfo.database.OrganizationRoles on item.UserOrgzRole equals gp.RoleId
                       select new {item.UserId,item.UName,item.UserLastName,gp.RoelName};
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                obs.Add(new RadAutoCompleteBoxItem { Content = item.UName + " " + item.UserLastName + " " + item.RoelName });
                Persondic.Add(item.UName + " " + item.UserLastName + " " + item.RoelName,item.UserId);
            }
```

DisplayMemberPath="Content"

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have an item not just with a string for its name, I need more info (like UID) for every item. Is there any solution??

You can accomplish this [using custom ItemTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/features/autocomplete#using-custom-itemtemplate) as shown in the  [CustomDropDownItemTemplate](https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk/tree/master/AutoCompleteBox/CustomDropDownItemTemplate) example:

[image]

Something along the lines of:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding obs}" DropDownItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomDropDownItemTemplate}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomDropDownItemTemplate">
  ... your layout goes here ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Edit: Also have a look at [Customizing the DropDownItemTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radautocompletebox/styles-and-templates/customizing-drop-down-itemtemplate)

Comment: thanks. itried this, BUT, when i search a text it did not show anything. see my code in Edit.

Comment: i have already copied and Pasted the example. i think the NAme and Capital Binding does not work. it shows me the country name for suggestion but when i select the item it brings an empty item, however the selected item in my C# code is correct, but it is not showed. just a box with a close button!! please HElp!!!